# Java Socket - Bind Object to IP

Tags: java, sockets, hashmap

I am trying to handle controllers for a game (like a splitscreen game, many controllers, one screen/game) but somehow I don't know what is best practise to do this? Currently I am trying to command the Player object by the socket's IP address so each controller controlls the rigth Player, but somehow I am binding the same IP to multiple Players (copy by reference mistakes?):

```
public class PlayerMapper {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(PlayerMapper.class.getName());

    private static final Map<byte[], Player> players = new HashMap<>();

    public static synchronized Player getPlayer(final InetAddress paramInetAddress) {
        return players.get(paramInetAddress.getAddress());
    }

    public static synchronized void addPlayer(final InetAddress paramInetAddress, final String paramName) {
        final byte[] address = paramInetAddress.getAddress();
        final Player player = players.get(address);
        if (null == player) {
            players.put(address, new Player(paramName));
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Player \"{}\" already connected!", player.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Testing this with the same "controller" aka "127.0.0.1" 5 times results in 5 different players, the values of the keys in the HashMap are all the same, but the references are different, even if I copy the byte array of the IP address?

Comment: Because they're all coming from the same IP? you can either use the port or even better just put the socket as the key.

Comment: The right thing here is not to rely on networking details to distinguish between your controller sessions. Have the controllers do something like generate (or receive) a unique session id when they connect and use that to track different players, reconnects, etc. As to the specific bug, the answers point out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array inherits the default Object `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods.  `Object#hashCode()` generates a hash code from the object's memory address, and `Object#equals()` compares only for object identity (are they the same object).

Thus two arrays will be treated as distinct keys in a `HashMap` even if they have the same contents.  To use arrays as a `HashMap` key you must wrap them in an object and provide custom `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementations.

Comment: Oh thank you! I changed byte[] to String and getAddress() to getHostName() and it worked! Yeah!

Comment: Just remember that IP address is generally useless for identifying socket clients except in very limited situations (local network only).  NAT means you can have _many_ clients behind a single IP address, and they would all look like the same client to your code.  Also, there may not be a hostname available if there is no reverse DNS mapping for the IP.  The only reliable way to identify clients is to establish a shared token (aka a "cookie") within your protocol.

Comment: the game will run in a LAN only and the controllers will be smartphones connected to the (W-)LAN so each controller has it's own IP I guess?

Comment: Again, using IP is just generally a bad idea, and using hostname is even worse.  What happens when a client phone wanders into a different WiFi router's range and gets a different IP address?  Change your protocol to establish a unique connection token for each client and use that for identification.

Comment: okay okay I got it I will use tokens or session IDs or something else unique :P

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not have an `equals` method (well, they do, but implementation is brain-dead), so you end up comparing references, and they are different.

Try using `paramInetAddress` itself as a key, not `.getAddress`

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked as well so I don't knwo why you got an downvote? Does your solution also work for many connections? What is compared in the HashMap if I use the InetAddress as key?